# javascript split( /\r\n|\n|\r/) with semicolon

Tags: javascript

I use the following code in javascript

```
console.log(result);
tmp = result.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
console.log(tmp);
```

to split the result which appears like:

> x = 1;
>
> y = 3;
>
> z = 4;

into an array tmp, but i get the semicolon(;) as well

> [ "x = 1;", "y = 3;", "z = 95;"]

what I need is

> [ "x = 1", "y = 3", "z = 95"]

without the semicolon, what should I add?

Comment: Why not `result.split(/[\n\r;]+/)`? Or `result.match(/[^\n\r;]+/g)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean semicolon and not question mark. Anyway as the parameter inside the split function is a regex you can change it to match also the semicolon. If you are sure the semicolon will be there just use this:

```
tmp = result.split(/;\r\n|;\n|;\r/);
```

If you are not sure the semicolon is always there just use this one:

```
tmp = result.split(/;?\r\n|;?\n|;?\r/);
```

The ? in the last regex mean '0 or 1' so it check if the semicolon is there and if it is it use it as separator.

Comment: I edited the answer as the semicolon need to be matched in all of the cases

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace them with nothing before doing the splitting:

```js
result = `x = 1;
y = 3;
z = 4;`
console.log(result);
tmp = result.replace(/;/g, "").split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
console.log(tmp);
```